# SecurityManager scope

Tags: java, security

I am trying to write a SecurityManager for a plugin base and I am wondering how/if I can make the permissions apply only to plugins which are in the plugins directory. Currently the permissions apply to everything.

```
import java.security.AccessControlContext;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Permission;

public class PluginSecurityManager extends SecurityManager {

public PluginSecurityManager() {
    this.context = AccessController.getContext();
     System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "res/security/policy.txt");
}

public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {
    this.checkPermission(perm, context);
}

public AccessControlContext getContext() {
    return context;
}

private final AccessControlContext context;
}
```

policy file

```
grant codeBase "file:/plugins/*" {
permission java.io.FilePermission "res/*", "read";
permission java.io.FilePermission "user.dir/ikaros-cache/cache.zip", "read";
permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`SecurityManager` already uses policy files by passing on checks to `AccessController`.

There's little reason to subclass `SecurityManager`. You need a permission to do so, so probably your call to `AccessController.getContext` is going to return effectively full permissions anyway.

Suppressing access checks by reflection given the plugin full permissions if they so require.

Edit: Oh, I also see you seem to be changing a system property after constructing a `SecurityManager` initialising related global state. In general these sorts of things will not be reread.